# Using Same CSS :not() statement for multiple classes

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

> ```
> .mat-header-cell:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)),
> .mat-cell:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
>     text-align     : right;
>     justify-content: right;
> }
> ```

how can i use :not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) for both `.mat-header` & `.mat-cell` commonly?

i want to use this :not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) statement once but i want it to apply for both `.mat-header` & `.mat-cell`

my css works but i want it to be simple and less codes

Comment: `:nth-child(n+3)` should select the third child and on. You *could* also use `:is(.mat-header-cell, .mat-cell):nth-child(n+3)` but browser support for `:is()` is still [mixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbso , In my case i want only these style apply for 1st and 2nd row.but i want to minimize the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use less or sass:

```
.mat-header-cell, .mat-cell {
  &:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    text-align     : right;
    justify-content: right;
  }
}
```

less : http://lesscss.org/

Comment: can't i do this with css ?. the code works i just didn't want to repeat `:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2))`.what if i have like 5 different classes. then i have to repeat it 5 times.

Comment: you can't do that with css. if you want to use css you can give specific  class to this two element, something like "not-nth-1-2", and use this class every time you want

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
.mat-header-cell,
.mat-cell {
  &:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    text-align     : right;
    justify-content: right;
  }
}
```

For more reference check this documentation - [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)

Let me know if you still face any issue.